# Type inference surprising behaviour

Tags: scala

Say I define the following class

```
class X[K, T](create: K => T) {

}
```

and then I defining the following:

```
class A {

    val cb = new X[Int, B](i => new B(i))  // infers type fine
    val cc = new X[Int, C](i => new C(0, i))  // cannot infer type and requires parameter type

    class B(i: Int) {}

    class C(i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
}
```

I am wondering why the compiler cannot infer the type for i in the creation of cc?

Thanks
Des

Comment: How can you do `new X[Int, B]` when the given function returns a `new C` and a `C` is not a `B`? Shouldn't it be `new X[Int, C](...)`?

Comment: Sorry, a typo on my part. Should have read: val cc = new X[Int, C]... Have updated

Comment: I have a hunch that the Scala compiler won't inspect the type of `C` in order to determine the type of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a typo:

```
val cc = new X[Int, C](i => new C(0, i))
```

With `new X[Int, B](i => new C(0, i))` you are telling compiler that `X` is of type `X[Int, B]` but rather providing the constructor argument `create` as `=> C` (which should be `=> B`).

Hence it throws an error that it expects `B` but you provided `C`

Comment: Was a typo. Correct! Now fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is incorrect. `C` is not a subtype of `B`, so you cannot instantiate an `X[Int, B]` with new C() unless `C` extends `B`.

For example, this code works fine:

```
class A {

  val cb = new X[Int, B](i => new B(i)) 
  val cc = new X[Int, B](i => new C(0, i))

  class B(i: Int) {}

  class C(i1: Int, i2: Int) extends B(i1){}
}
```

Comment: Made a typo. Updated accordingly.